# move listbox item to another listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I want to use each listbox1 item to run the both query and if both result are not same than move that item to another listbox called listbox2 if they are same than delete that item from listbox1.

```
foreach (string Items in listBox1.Items)
{
    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from(( select * from all_ind_columns where  index_name= '" + Items + "'  and table_owner='" + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "'))", conn1))
    using (OracleCommand ctCommand = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from(( select * from all_ind_columns where  index_name= '" + Items + "'  and table_owner='" + txtDesUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "'))", conn1))
    {
        string result1 = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string result2 = ctCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (result1 != result2)
        {
            //move that item to listbox2
        }
        else if(result1 == result2)
        {
            // remove that item from listbox1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And then, what happened then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use `foreach` here because you change the `listBox1.Items` inside the loop,
Use while loop and check the `listBox1.Items.Count() >0` and inside the loop you can pic first item and move it to second one or remove.

```
while (ListBox1.Items.Count>0)
{
    var item =  ListBox1.Items[0].ToString();

    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from(( select * from all_ind_columns where  index_name= '" + item + "'  and table_owner='" + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "'))", conn1))
    using (OracleCommand ctCommand = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from(( select * from all_ind_columns where  index_name= '" + item + "'  and table_owner='" + txtDesUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "'))", conn1))
    {
        string result1 = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string result2 = ctCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (result1 != result2)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item);
        }
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }   

}
```

**Note:** *your code is open for sql injection attacks, use parameters instead of inline parameters.*

```
while (ListBox1.Items.Count>0)
{
    var item =  ListBox1.Items[0].ToString();

    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from(( select * from all_ind_columns where  index_name= :item  and table_owner=:table_owner))";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper());

        string result1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(txtDesUserID.Text.ToUpper());
        string result2 = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (result1 != result2)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item);
        }
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I use while loop here?

Comment: well this while loop is infinite because; there is always item inside the while loop and it doesnt go to listbox1.items.removeAt(0); it doesnt stop to check loop condition?...

Comment: @user2619275 i have change the code, if the results are matching you need to add that item to ListBox2, even you add or not finally you going to remove that item from ListBox1, so one by one items will remove from ListBox1. no infinite loop

Comment: Please not that my second ctCommand diffent at txtDesUserID.Text.ToUpper()

Comment: @user2619275 yes noted, that's why i'm set parameter value again

Comment: I got the below error:      'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)